# ROR : : submit button should only work for one click and not for second

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i am new to ruby on rails and i am stuck at a place in a form where the submit button should work only once and it should redirect to the same page there after.i am pasting the code snippet which i have used.

```
<%= f.submit "save" ,:class=>"paypal_save_btn_newusernegotiationnew"%>

if params[:submit] == "publish"
    format.html { redirect_to @offerdetail, notice: 'Offerdetail was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @offerdetail, status: :created, location: @offerdetail }

    else
    format.html { render action: "new_offerdetail" }
    format.json { render json: @offerdetail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

1. so far behaviour is that on first click it redirects to the same
   page and on second click it redirects to default page which is named
   "show" but i want it to be redirected to the same page.
2. second problem is on first click it saves data in the right tables
       which is named "offerdetail"(this is scaffolded) and "fetchfrom"
       (added model),but   on second click data is stored in scaffolded
       table and not in added model but i am using added model("fetchfrom")
       in other forms for accessing data.

desired behaviour is:

1. for any number of clicks on submit button it should redirect to same
   page.
2. data should be saved in both tables.

code for controller is

```
def create
  #To show purchaser infromation
  if fb_current_user
    @msgs=""
    @purchaser_first_name=fb_current_user.first_name
    @purchaser_last_name=fb_current_user.last_name
    @purchaser_email=fb_current_user.email
    @purchaser_gender=fb_current_user.gender
    @purchaser_birthdate=fb_current_user.birthday
  else
    @msgs="Please login to Facebook"
  end    

  @offerdetail = Offerdetail.new(params[:offerdetail])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @offerdetail.save
      # To save current offerid and assigning "0" to usernegotiation_id in Fetchfrom table 
      @fetchfrom = FetchFrom.new
      @fetchfrom.offer_id=Offerdetail.last.offerid
      @fetchfrom.usernegotiation_id=0
      @fetchfrom.final_purchase_price=Offerdetail.last.price
      @fetchfrom.total_coupons=Offerdetail.last.cou
      @fetchfrom.user_id = fb_current_user.id

      @fetchfrom.save                 

      @offer_id = @offerdetail.offerid
      #To show order_details
      @offer_value=Offer.find(@offerdetail.offerid).value
      @offer_purchaseprice =Offer.find(@offerdetail.offerid).purchaseprice
      @name = Offer.find(@offerdetail.offerid).nameofdeal
      @retailer_id = RetailersOffer.find_by_offer_id(@offerdetail.offerid).retailer_id
      @business_name = Retailer.find(@retailer_id ).name

        if params[:submit] == "publish"
        format.html { redirect_to new_offerdetail, notice: 'Offerdetail was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: new_offerdetail, status: :created, location: new_offerdetail }

        else
        format.html { render action: "new_offerdetail" }
        format.json { render json: new_offerdetail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
  end

end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you need to give some more code here. especially the header of the form and the controller code, would be needed in order to figure out the redirects

Comment: @fly.floh:  Thank you very much for suggestion i will post the code

Comment: what action in the controller is that? is the same action called, when you klick the button the second time?
your view code for the form would be helpful as well..

Comment: @prasvin: please help me with the code

Comment: @ken - I'll need more info. Can you add your form that contains the button you are talking about, and the action that renders the form. So, provide the action before the form is rendered, the form and the action which the submit button goes to(I hope this is the `create` action which you have already posted).

Comment: I can't even look at this unless you move all those multiple lines into their own method(s).  Chances are rails conventions can deal with them anyway.  No point using rails unless you use it's conventions.